# How to make synchronous calls on a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to *enqueue* an `Action` with a separate `ManualResetEvent` into function queue like

```
Enqueue(() =>
{
   function();
   ManualResetEvent evt;
});
evt.WaitOne();
```

on the thread which takes action from the function queue, and execute the action

```
Action action = queue.dequeue();
action();
```

I want to do: `evt.Set();` here
my question is how can I get that `ManualResetEvent` object, as in the debugger I can see action's Target has that ManualResetEvent evt

Comment: Let's edit your question, especially where has source code.

Comment: why do you want a ManualResetEvent when you only execute the action after dequeue?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I have a feeling that there's a solution to your underlying problem that does pass through the question you have asked

Answer (score 0):

Don't enqueue the `Action`, rather enqueue an object instance (that you need to define) that has a property of type `Action` and a property of the `ManualResetEvent`, then you have access to both